# Need help in using CheckedTextView in android

Tags: android

I have the following in my layout.xml file:

```
<CheckedTextView 
    android:id="@+id/checktext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingRight="6dip"
/>
```

It shows the 'radio button', but when I call in my onClickListener()?

```
CheckedTextView numberView2 = (CheckedTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.checktext);
numberView2.setSelected(true);
v.invalidate();
```

It does not show the 'radio button' as selected. I have stepped via the source code, it does execute 'numberView2.setSelected(true);', but it still does not show the radio button as selected.

Can you please tell me why is that? And how can I fix my problem.

Comment: Why are you invalidating the whole parent View and not just `numberView2`?

Comment: I don't know. I was trying everything I can think of to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you don't want setChecked instead of setSelected?